# How to move a sprite with the gyroscope?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gyroscope

I have a unity3d game, and I want to move only the X position of my sprite using the phone's gyroscope. Do you know how can I do that?

Comment: A gyroscope just gives angles, how do you want that to translate into a position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean 'moving' in the sense that it falls into the direction the device is tilted to, you need to get the euler angles of the rotation, and apply a force on the x and y axes, where x is the x rotation and y is the z rotation. If it doesn't work like expected, try using different rotation axes.
Something like this:

```
Vector3 euler = gyroscopeRotation.Euler();
rigidbody.AddForce(euler.x, euler.z);
```

If you want your ball to be more sensitive to tilt, multiply `euler.x` and `euler.z` by a value that fits your needs